# Why is my adder giving me the wrong output?

Tags: adder

So I made this circuit right from my professor's notes. It is a carry ripple adder. I've been testing it out and one of the problems it has is this:

When you turn on all three inputs, it does not give you three as an answer. Instead I get two.

[image: Circuit]

Here's simplified output we used to make the circuit:
[image]

Comment: Look at the truth table for the 3-input Ex-or gate, which is the only thing involved in determining the low bit. When you 'made' this circuit, what exactly did you use?

Comment: I used logisim. I'll add the truth table used.

Comment: Consider that there may be more than one way to define a multiple-input Ex-or gate.

Comment: I updated the question as well.

Comment: Is this enough of a hint?

Comment: Not really. I found some other simple adders online, so I know it is not the software. I am wondering why my professor would give us this example if it will not work. It's not just in his notes but the same example is in the textbook I am using.

Comment: Okay, try doing 2 cascaded 2-input ex-or gates rather than a 3-input.

Comment: I actually gave you the answer as to where the problem exactly is, but it's been converted to a comment, so perhaps whoever did that could do the rest of your homework for you.

Comment: @Spehro I figured out the problem. It is an issue with logisim. Logisims XOR gates have an option which decides outcome between 3 inputs.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/p/circuit/discussion/479544/thread/e874d0a7/

^The answer is explained in this discussion. It's not a bug but a "feature" in logisim.

> "This is not a bug, but rather a design decision that you happen to disagree with. How XOR is "supposed" to work is more controversial than you seem to think. By default, Logisim takes the interpretation that a XOR gate means "exactly one" bit must be set: Thus, the XOR of three 1's is 0, since more than one of input is 1. I know you think that the XOR of three 1's should be 1, since an odd number of bits are 1. If Logisim were changed to work your way by default, then others would complain that I broke the XOR gate - admittedly fewer people, but still a substantial fraction of Logisim users.
>   Fortunately, Logisim does have the ability for you to modify the XOR gate's behavior: With the XOR gate selected, go to the attribute table in the lower-left corner, and modify "Multiple-Input Behavior" to "When an odd number are on." Alternatively, you can use an Odd Parity gate."